# Ansible array variable

Tags: variable, array, ansible

I have a template file `config.j2`.

```
{% for host in groups['dbs'] %}
ips= {{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

My output is:

```
   ips= 192.168.231.91
   ips= 192.168.231.92
   ips= 192.168.231.93
```

I want save the output in an array variable like this:

`ips=192.168.231.91,192.168.231.92,192.168.231.93`

How can do this? thanks.

**Edit and output after finding a solution:**

```
  - set_fact:
  ips: []  
  run_once: true

- set_fact:
  ips: "{{ips}} + ['{{hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address}}']"  
  with_inventory_hostnames:
  - dbs  
  run_once: true

- name: Save ip servers
  template: src=conf.j2 dest=/root


TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [db1]
ok: [db2]
ok: [db3]

TASK [get-var : set_fact] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [db1]

TASK [get-var : set_fact] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [db1] => (item=db1)
ok: [db1] => (item=db3)
ok: [db1] => (item=db2)

TASK [get-var : Save ip servers] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [db1]
ok: [db2]
ok: [db3]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************
db1                        : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
db2                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
db3                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

---

Finally output in template on hosts (dbs):

```
[root@db1 ~]# cat conf.j2 
ips=[]
[root@db1 ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution in a playbook would be to initialize an empty list, then append to it [looping over hostnames in your inventory group](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-the-inventory):

```
- set_fact:
    ips: []
  run_once: true

- set_fact:
    ips: "{{ips}} + ['{{hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address}}']"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - dbs
  run_once: true

- template:
    src: config.j2
    dest: /tmp/whatever
```

with a template file `config.j2` containing

```
ips={{ ips|to_yaml }}
```

Comment: thanks for answered. but array is empty. please look edit question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it working

```
  - set_fact:
      ips="[]"
    run_once: true

  - set_fact:
      ips="{{ ips }} + ['{{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}']"  
    with_inventory_hostnames:
      - dbs
    run_once: true

  - name: get ip list locally
    local_action: copy content="{{ ips }}" dest=files/nodes
    run_once: true
```

files/nodes

```
["192.168.1.13", "192.168.1.8", "192.168.1.14", "192.168.1.6", "192.168.1.9"]
```

Comment: If you want to bypass writing to a file, the array is there for a template to use
{% for ip in ips %}"{{ ip }}"{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

if you use variable ansible_host for each host in your inventory
You can do it like this:

```
- set_fact: nodelist={%for host in groups['dbs']%}{{hostvars[host].ansible_host}}{% 
if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

OR by your conditions:

```
- set_fact: nodelist={%for host in groups['dbs']%} 
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% 
endfor %}
```

Note: code should be in one line.